# Prove that $\lim_{x \to a} x^4 = a^4$ using epsilon-delta definition

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-verification

This is an exercise in Spivak's calculus:

> Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}: x \mapsto x^4$. Prove that $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = a^ 4$

Is my proof correct?

**Proof**: Let $\epsilon > 0$. If $|x-a| < 1$, it follows that $|x| < 1 + |a|$

and hence: $$|x^3 + x^2a + xa^2 + a^3| \leq |x|^3 + |x|^2|a| + |x||a|^2 + |a|^3 $$$$< ((1+|a|)^3 + (1+|a|)^2|a| + (1+|a|)|a|^2 + |a|^3$$

Choose $\delta =  \min\left\{\frac{\epsilon}{(1+|a|)^3 + (1+|a|)^2|a| + (1+|a|)|a|^2 + |a|^3},1\right\}$

Then, for $x \in \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $0 < |x-a| < \delta$, we have:

$$|x^4-a^4| = |x-a||x^3 + x^2a + xa^2 + a^3| 
<|x-a|((1+|a|)^3 + (1+|a|)^2|a| + (1+|a|)|a|^2 + |a|^3)$$
$$< \delta((1+|a|)^3 + (1+|a|)^2|a| + (1+|a|)|a|^2 + |a|^3) \leq \epsilon$$

Hence, the result follows.

Comment: It's just fine.

Comment: Yes, that works.  A little precise but ... why not?

Comment: Isn't it the goal of these exercises to be precise?

Comment: The goal is to be rigorous and clear.  Showing that $\delta$ exists in a clear and concise way may be better than finding the largest possible $\delta.$

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, while this is correct, in such contexts, simpler bounds are generally preferred over sharp ones. So for instance, in this case, you can do

|(a+h)<sup>4</sup>-a<sup>4</sup>| = |4a<sup>3</sup>h+6a<sup>2</sup>h<sup>2</sup>+4ah<sup>3</sup>+h<sup>4</sup>|

From here, you can replace all the coefficients with 6. If a<1, you can replace each  of its powers by 1, and if a>1, you can replace each of its powers by a<sup>3</sup>. We can assume h<1, so we can replace all of its powers by h. Hence,

|(a+h)<sup>4</sup>-a<sup>4</sup>|<|6*max(a<sup>3</sup>,1)h|

We can therefore take $\delta$ to be any number < $\epsilon$/[6*min(a<sup>3</sup>,1)]